# How to alter node title link?

Tags: hooks

I want alter `$node_url` in `node.tpl.php` inside a module not in `node.tpl.php`, which `hook` should I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is done in `template_preprocess_node()` in node.module on line 1451 (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7).

```
function template_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  ...
  $variables['node_url']  = url($uri['path'], $uri['options']);
  ...
```

You could change it to anything else in your own module in `mymodule_preprocess_node()` function like so:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['node_url'] = 'some/other/path';
}
```